# Why do we need to use the chain rule to differentiate $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ with respect to $t$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

In the following example, taken from the Stewart's Calculus book, we are told that to differentiate the formula for volume, we need to use the chain rule:

> In order to connect $dV/dt$ and $dr/dt$, we first relate $V$ and $r$ by the formula for the volume of a sphere:$$V=\frac43\pi r^3$$ In order to use the given information, we differentiate each side of this equation with respect to $t$. To differentiate the right side, we need to use the Chain Rule: $$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}=4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$$

I don't understand why, since on the right side we don't have a composite function ($\frac{4}{3}  \pi$ is simply  a constant). Can somebody please explain this?

[image]

Comment: $r$ must be a function of independent variable $t$, otherwise the term $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is zero

Comment: Define $r$ as a function of $t$. Let $r = f(t)$. You don't need chain rule here. Define $g(x) = x^3$. So, $\frac43 \pi r^3 = \frac 43 \pi g(f(t))$ which is a composite function, so you _need_ the chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *do* have a composite function, since $V$ depends on $r$, where $r$ depends on $t$. So in the end $V$ depends on $t$:
$$
V = \tfrac{4\pi}{3}  r(t)^3
.
$$

Answer (score 2):

In this problem $r$ is the radius of a balloon that is being inflated. Therefore, $r$ is increasing with time. That is, $r=r(t)$ and $V=V(r)=V(r(t))$.